# Get claim email address

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I want to access my email address via `Claim` inside `Identity`

I tried accessing as:

```
var email = User.Identity.GetClaimsByType("emailaddress").ToString();
var email = User.Identity.GetClaimsByType("email").ToString();
var email = User.Identity.GetClaimsByType("Email").ToString();
```

But none of these works, it always return `null`, how can I get it?

The claim is:

```
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress: MyemailAdrress@mail.com}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# offers a [Claim Types Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes.email?view=net-5.0) to represent the claim type url. The code would look like this:

```
var email = User.Identity.GetClaimsByType(ClaimTypes.Email)
    .Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

If you support custom Claim Types in your identity, you could use LINQ.

```
var claimValue = User.Identity.Claims
    .FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type.Contains(<my custom claim type>));
```

Comment: So use that is the same as use something like:  `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"`?